# Notepad++ plugin to edit opening and closing html tags at the same time

Tags: plugins, textmate, notepad++

Is there a plugin (or a way) to edit opening and closing html tags in Notepad++ simultaneously such as the 'Insert open/close tag' feature of Textmate?

Edit simultaneously: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=jqj1t4qFFwM#t=20s

Insert open/close tag feature: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=jqj1t4qFFwM#t=15s

Surround.vim is a somewhat similar feature but for VIM.

Comment: I pine for editing the opening tag, while typing the closing tag gets updated as well - _without_ highlighting the end tag (a-la multiple edit feature).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a plugin that does this at the moment, sorry.

However, it wouldn't be impossible to add, especially with the existing tag highlighting code  (full disclosure: I wrote the current tag highlighting code).  Add an "idea" on ideatorrent on the sourceforge project page.  It's certainly something that's asked about often enough.